# shell script: how to group rows according to the first field/element in each row

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file  with rows like:

```
1 24 4
1 2 3
1 5 9
2 1 8
2 3 4
```

I want to use shell scripts to group these rows by the first element in each row. For example, we have 3 rows with the first element '1', then I want to put the second element, namely "24, 2 5" together with the first element in the same row, the grouping result is:

```
1 24 2 5
2 1 3
```

how can I do this using shell scripts? thanks!

Comment: Is your first column sorted or in random order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is sorted based on first column then you can just print column 1 padded with column 2 as they change. Something like:

```
awk '
$1!=fld1 && NR>1{
    print fld1, fld2
    fld1 = $1; fld2 = $2
    next
}
{
    fld1 = $1; 
    fld2 = ((fld2) ? fld2 FS $2 : $2)
}
END{print fld1, fld2}' file
1 24 2 5
2 1 3
```

If your input is random then you are better off storing the values in array.

```
awk '{a[$1] = ((a[$1]) ? a[$1] FS $2 : $2)}
END{for(x in a) print x,a[x]}' file 
1 24 2 5
2 1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk '!a[$1]{b[++p]=$1; a[$1]=$2;next} {a[$1]=sprintf("%s%s%s", a[$1], OFS, $2)}
      END {for (i=1; i<=p; i++) print b[i], a[b[i]]}' file
1 24 2 5
2 1 3
```